# Fetch all again from db after inserting one item?

Tags: next.js

So im sitting in a Next.js app. I have a form and a list of items, so far. When I submit a new item via the form, it posts to the db and then show the new item in the list.

Would you say it is better to fetch the entire list, replace the state, from the db again after posting a new item? Or is it better to insert this new item directly into the state, on top? And only fetch the entire list again on reload

Answer (score 0):

I would say my opinion depends on how important is it to maintain the "source of truth" of the data: i.e. is it important that the data is intimately linked to the data that is on the database.
Otherwise if not then one thing that you can do is to send the new item in the list to the database and wait for it to either succeed or fail. If it succeeds then you can add the item to the list locally. (One way this will not work is if the user is using multiple tabs sending items - it will not be syncronized across tabs)

Either way when the user submits the form then you should be validating their inputs server-side anyway.
Hope this helps, if you want further advice more information is needed about the code and its context.